# What is the direction for interoperability between Desktop Duplication API and Vulkan

Tags: windows, vulkan, dxgi

How do or will interoperability of surfaces / textures work between APIs going forward?

Let's say we all continue to move to Vulkan.  However, the best way to capture (for my application) is DXGI Desktop Duplication.  How will these connect?

In the past, I could optimize things and, if the captured area was on the same graphics adapter as the render target, keep the captured texture on the GPU.

In a case where all rendering is Vulkan, what happens?  Will everyone just have to pull textures back to CPU and send them back down, or is there a current or emerging technology to share surfaces, textures, or frame buffers between different drivers with different APIs?

Comment: You should be able to interface with shared handles in vulkan using *VK_KHR_external_memory_win32*. From there you just have to use D3D's shared resource functions.

Comment: @vandench awesome contribution, thanks!  That's the sort of pointer I was looking for.  I think the question would be then if Vulkan uses such a shared handle to a buffer captured on the DXGI side, would it have to be pulled back to CPU like normal shared handle usage, before it then gets redownloaded to GPU via Vulkan?   Or would it actually be shared GPU buffer to GPU buffer, effectively?   I hope that's not a super dumb question :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the user mode device drivers are responsible for creating the shared handles, thus they have full control over their residency. To my understanding, the drivers for a given device will try to avoid transferring back to the CPU, but there may be circumstances where that may not be possible. ie it’s probably up to the drivers.

Comment: @vandench you are a rock star.   You should have just made that an answer instead of comment.

Comment: Looking into it, it appears that DXGI Desktop Duplication doesn't even need to rely on shared resources, and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nn-dxgi1_2-idxgioutputduplication#remarks) say that it can intrinsically access the image of an opengl application (which for your purposes is no different than a vulkan application). Can you provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) sample of how you're currently trying to use DXGI Desktop Duplication?

Comment: @vandench I cannot at this time.  This is still me doing the research.  My previous code was all Direct3D and DXGI, and I just made sure I notice when the capture area and the display area are on the same graphics adapter so I can directly use the captured frame as a texture and draw it without it ever going to CPU.  In the multi-adapter case, you do need to set it up a bit different and pull back to CPU and re-render on the stack for the other card, basically.   I think you have already done heroic work answering, I will just try to make it work if and when I get to a working Vulkan app.